# How to delete all defined SymPy symbols without explicitly listing them?

Tags: python, sympy

SymPy and Python newbie here.

I run a script that iterates over a number of test files. Each file defines a set of symbols to use. At the end of each loop iteration, I want to delete all the symbols created earlier using the `symbols()` statement and nothing more, since I have other non-symbol variables around I am using.

I can't do  `del(x)` and `del(y)` since each iteration will load a different set of symbols.

I can put a list of the symbols used in a list, or tuple, then at end of each iteration, go over the list of symbols that was created, and delete them one at a time using `del` But I can't get this to work.

Here is an example.

```
 from sympy import *
 x,y = symbols('x y')
 symbolsToDelete = (x,y) #I also tried symbolsToDelete = ('x','y')

 x=y**3
 y=99

 #now I want to delete all symbols defined above. But I can't
 #use del(x) or del(y) explicitly. So I tried

 for z0 in symbolsToDelete:
     del(z0)
```

But the above does not work, `x` and `y` are still there, with `x=y**3` and `y=99`.

Again, I know I can do `del(x)` and `del(y)` at the end, but I am reading the names of the variables from a file, and the names are in a list.

I could only put the symbols in one variable like I did above, but do not know how to iterate over this tuple and then use `del()` on each entry to remove the corresponding symbol defined above at end of iteration using `symbols` command.

I do not know what the correct syntax should be.

I am using Python **3.6.5**.

Comment: As an aside: after `y=99` the Python variable `y` is not a SymPy symbol anymore, it's just a Python integer 99. The previous assignment `y = symbols('y')` is completely forgotten. It is unadvisable to think of SymPy symbols as "variables" because they _do not vary_: they are immutable, they cannot be "assigned a value".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your attempt did not work is explained in [Delete all objects in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465279/delete-all-objects-in-a-list) - when looping over `[x, y]` you are deleting additional references to the objects (created in the process of iteration), while the original references stay in place.

You can delete `x` and `y` by accessing them via [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) as follows

```
symbolsToDelete = ('x', 'y')

for z0 in symbolsToDelete:
    del globals()[z0]
```