# How to delete everything inside an object in a json file but keep the object?

Tags: python, json

I want to delete everything in the object "name" in the given json file example but keep the the object, in simple words I want to clear the object.

```
{

    "names": [

        {

            "player": "Player_Name",

            "TB:": "12389",

            "BW:": "596",

            "SW:": "28",

            "CQ:": "20"

        }

    ]

}
```

I used tried this code:

```
with open('players.json', 'w') as w:
    with open('players.json', 'r') as r:
        for line in r:
            element = json.loads(line.strip())
            if 'names' in element:
                del element['names']
            w.write(json.dumps(element))
```

but it just clears the whole json file

sorry for my bad english

Comment: The key must have some value so maybe *element['names'] = []*

Comment: First of all find a tutorial and learn how to work (read/write) json file in python.  Then check https://stackoverflow.com/q/14465279/4046632 or simply set the value for key `names` to be empty list.

Comment: `w.write(json.dumps({}))`

Comment: `json.dump({'names': []}, file)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all objects in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465279/delete-all-objects-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you open the same file twice - for reading and for writing simultaneously. Also a JSON cannot be parsed line by line, only as a whole.

```
import json

# 1. read
with open('players.json', 'r') as r:
    data = json.load(r)

# 2. modify
# (you might want to check if data is a dict)
data['names'] = []


# 3. write
with open('players.json', 'w') as w:
    data = json.dump(data, w)
```

Comment: it works but i want to keep the names list but it should be empty

Comment: @PonguinxD I have updated the code.